# Discord.js v12 Message On Ban

Tags: discord, discord.js

I don't know the syntax to do an action when a user is banned.
It's also fine for discord.js v11.5.2.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?

Answer (score 2):

```js
<GuildMember>.ban();
```

Get a guild member instance by something like `msg.mentions.members.first()`

Docs:

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=ban

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/examples/moderation